# Checking in with server in the background in Java-Android

Tags: java, android, multithreading, service

I am trying to write an app that checks in with a server every X seconds.

I was able to make it work, but only when the application is running and active (not sure if it can be minimized, was not able to test it clearly) and the device is not locked. I would like for the checking to continue even if I lock the device or do other things on it.

From my searches, it seems like I should use service, but I was not able to figure out how to implement it with what I am trying to do. Or is there something else that could do this?

What I need to and failed to do is this:

1. User checks a CheckBox - start the service
2. Create the service and pass some information to it
3. Create an instance of my class in the service using the passed information
4. Call this instance's method every X seconds in a new thread (the method returns true/false)
5. Listen to ?something and if the method returns true then stop the service and notify user
6. If the user unchecks the CheckBox, stop the service.

I tried doing this, but I was unable to get any information out of the thread and out of the service. Is there a way to do so?

Comment: first of all, you want to have always working service or just after checkbox? Should it autostart?

Comment: After the checkbox is ticked, it shouldn't start without the user's interaction.

Comment: check my unswer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Starting the service from activity for example and binding it with your app

```
//make these 2 variables as fields in Activity for example
    YourService yourService = null;
//this variable can be used for checking if your activity are binded already or not
    boolean mBounded = false;


Intent mIntent = new Intent(this, YourService.class);
startService(mIntent);
bindService(mIntent, mConnection, BIND_AUTO_CREATE);

ServiceConnection mConnection = new ServiceConnection() {
    public void onServiceDisconnected(ComponentName name) {
        mBounded = false;
        yourService = null;
    }

    public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName name, IBinder service) {
        mBounded = true;
        YourService.LocalBinder mLocalBinder = (YourService.LocalBinder) service;
        yourService= mLocalBinder.getServerInstance();
    }
};
```

Do not forget that you can use methods from Service in Activity only after it is bound to your Activity. In other words it is available only after `onServiceConnected` is executed. 
So you have now service and activity who can communicate with each other.
For example you can call in Activity some public method of your Service, like

```
if (yourService != null)
    yourService.test();
```

If you want to call your Activity methods in Service you should pass it to Service with simple setter.

If you want to stop Service its kinda easy too:

```
  Intent mIntent = new Intent(this, YourService.class);
  stopService(mIntent);
```

For doing request every X service:

1) You can do infinity separate thread inside Service and do request after delay for X seconds.

2) For checking every X seconds you can use something like `AlarmManager`.

3) Also its possible to use `CountDownTimer` inside your Service to do some requests to server.

If you want to create your Service after reboot if CheckBox was set, its easy too. So you should use simple `BroadcastReceiver`.

First of all you should save your CheckBox setting in `SharedPreferences`, then run your Service if you need.

```
public class SimpleReceiver extends WakefulBroadcastReceiver{

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

        //run below code if you need, depends on your saved value of Checkbox in SharedPreferences
        Intent serviceIntent = new Intent(context, YourService.class);
        context.startService(serviceIntent);
    }
}
```

And for sure dont forget to add in `AndroidManifest` information about your `Service` and `Receiver` to be sure it will run automatically after reboot.

```
<service
    android:name=".package.YourService"
    android:enabled="true"
    android:exported="false"> </service>

<receiver
    android:name=".package.SimpleReceiver"
    android:enabled="true"
    android:exported="true">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
        <action adroid:name="android.intent.action.QUICKBOOT_POWERON" />
    </intent-filter> 
</receiver>
```

Comment: I am sorry, but I am not sure how to implement this solution. 

I have an activity class with a method that is called when my checkbox is clicked. Then I have another class that stores the information about connecting and the methods to connect. 

I don't need the service to do anything else than create an object, call it's methods in a new thread and stop when true is returned. Where does the ServiceConnection come in?

Comment: ServiceConnection for sure should be in Activity in place where do you want to start service. For example in your checkbox listener.

Comment: If you need to create your object in Service do it in onStartCommand in Service.

Comment: So the whole "ServiceConnection mConnection = new..." should be in the 'If checkbox is checked' statement?

Comment: In your case I think yes

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I will have to take a look into it :)